# Name is not bound in this Context... Datasource not found

Tags: jersey, datasource, postgresql-9.3, tomcat8

Am building a small Jersey (1.9) REST Service and having a Java class as sub-resource where I connect to local database (Postgres 9.3).

For the datasource I have already add the entries in Context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/userProfile">
   <Resource
      auth="Container"
      driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      maxActive="100"
      maxIdle="30"
      maxWait="10000"
      name="jdbc/apiUserProfile"
      password="postgres"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/apiUserProfile"
      username="postgres"/>
</Context>
```

When I run the application and call the following resource:

```
http://localhost:8084/userProfile/rest/user/conn
```

the page is blank - no content- and the tomcat (8.0) on netbeans (8.1) is throwing Error: Null Pointer Exception

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/apiUserProfile] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at net.rest.dao.DbConn.apiUserProfileConn(DbConn.java:23)
at net.rest.service.userProfile.returnDatabaseStatus(userProfile.java:51)
```

I also already have the JAR files in the librairies:

```
lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar
lib/postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc4.jar
```

and here is the sub-resource class for the datasource connection:

```
package net.rest.dao;

import javax.naming.*;
import javax.sql.*;

public class DbConn {
    private static DataSource DbConn = null;
    private static Context context = null;
    public static DataSource apiUserProfileConn() throws Exception {
        if(DbConn != null){
           return DbConn;
        }
        try {
            if(context == null){
               context = new InitialContext();
            }
            DbConn = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/apiUserProfile");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return DbConn;
    }
}
```

Any Idea pls. how to fix this..

Many Thanks

a.kasbi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now.. the Apache Tomcat Doc was very helpful:

```
http://localhost:8080/docs/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html
http://localhost:8080/docs/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#PostgreSQL
```

The solution for me was adding the following into context.xml under: META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/apiRest">
   <Resource name="jdbc/apiUserProfile" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/apiUserProfile"
      username="postgres" password="postgres" maxTotal="20" maxIdle="10"
      maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
</Context>
```

and the following in web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>postgreSQL Datasource example</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/apiUserProfile</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

The lookup argument in the java Class for the Datasource connection:

```
...
DbConn = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/apiUserProfile");
...
```

Thanks